# Eclipse SQL Code Assist

Tags: sql, eclipse, code-assist

Is there some trick to getting SQL Code Assist working in Eclipse? I have opened an SQL scrapbook page, assigned it a type, connection name and database.. and tried to type some SQL.

If I enter a schema name..

```
select * from public.
```

It shows me a list of tables.. so I can select one and get:

```
select * from public.batch_job_instance
```

but that's it. Once I start on the WHERE clause there is no help. It doesn't matter whether I put public or public.batch_job_instance (or just hurl obscenities at my monitor for five minutes - I tried that a few times) there is no further "assistance".

How exactly do I get this code assist to assist me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse sql code completion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957656/eclipse-sql-code-completion)

Comment: As an update, I no longer use the default database tooling in Eclipse. Instead, I now use DBeaver for Eclipse - it is magnificent and has much better tooling for code assisting SQL.