# Eclipse sql code completion

Tags: sql, eclipse, code-completion

I also am wondering why I cannot get Eclipse to complete the following for me:

```
Select X from dbo.table.xxxx
```

It will give me the table but not any columns.  I am using Indigo and have Data Tools installed.  Am I expecting something it is not designed to do?

db = Sybase 12.x, I tried using the JDBC and JTDS drivers for both 12.x and 15.x

JDBC is using jconn3.  JTDS is 1.2.5 I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at this newsgroup post
http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/dtp-dev/msg01630.html

it explains why it doesn't work and it might be fixed in future versions

Comment: Thanks.  That post says that it should work if you type the table name in first...but that doesn't even work for me.   Since that was a 2008 comment I will assume they never got around to putting that functionality together.  Life goes on!